# GRUB shows up unexpectedly when booting after CMOS Reset

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd, grub, bootloader

Basically, my computer has 3 hard drives. 2 HDDs, 1 SSD. Years ago, I installed a Linux partition on one of the HDDs, but decided to move back to solely using Winodws(gaming pc) and removed Linux from this device. Currently I have my OS(Windows 7), installed on my SSD.

In an attempt to plug in my phone to a rear USB port at night, I managed to accidentally hit my clear CMOS button and reboot the system. Not a big deal. Until everything booted up, and I somehow found myself stuck in GRUB looking at a boot selection of MINT and Windows 7. Neither of which will actually exist anymore, because MINT is gone and Windows 7 is on another drive. I'm able to get back into my computer by selecting one of the two HDDs(didn't look at which one), which makes zero sense because all logic dictates Windows and the boot partition for it should be on the SSD.

My question is this:

1. How is this possible?
2. What can I do to remove GRUB entirely so I don't get stuck in
   infinite boot fails when it tries to load an OS that's no longer
   there?

*Note: TL;DR - GRUB wasn't erased when I re-installed Windows and it's trying to control the boot sequence now.*

Comment: Looks like GRUB was installed to another HDD but that wasn't the default boot device of late. Resetting your BIOS to defaults changed the boot order back to that drive and thus the resurrection of GRUB. If you set the boot order so that the SSD with Win7 is the first boot device, it should work fine like you were used to.

Comment: See, that makes good sense, but my huge wall I'm hitting is why Windows is on one drive, and it's booting off of another.. Also if this is the case is there a way to remove grub, move windows entirely onto the SSD, bootloader and all, without having to reinstall everything and nuke all three drives first? Trying to avoid that. EDIT: I can set BIOS to boot off the proper drive, but that's only redirecting the issue. I'd like to get rid of GRUB and fix the absolute cluster I've made out of my drives.

Comment: Boot partition can be on another drive. Disconnect all other drives except the SSD and check if it boots into Win7 or not. If yes then that means that drive is independent and not a problem. If GRUB on one of the HDDs is an issue, use something like `bootsect /nt60 <drive:> /mbr` (from Windows Setup media) to remove it, although there's no real problem leaving it there if you switch the SSD back to being the default boot device.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I was aiming to have the SSD completely independent as it was, and it seemed I had accomplished that until all of this happened. Apparently my drives are a mess- GRUB thinks I have two copies of Mint, one Win7, and my proper Win7 boot thinks I have two copies of windows that both boot into the same thing. I broke something somewhere but I'll start with this to try and remove GRUB and check where Windows is properly booting from.

Answer (score 0):

how was grub setup to probe for drives originally  by uuid perhaps?

If so:

1) if anything in the initial grub entry for mint or original win 7 entry had a failover aka  "if you don't find this resort to that..." it would appear it is  reverting to the ssd finding nada on the connected hdds ---which while not impossible is Really really rare and odd..

2) Do you have a windows install disk or know how to enter recovery or safe mode after booted into windows?  if so all that is needed is a bcd repair or edit (aka reinstall windows bootloader which will totally wipe out grub --which may not be as safe in my opinion but not my system )

Comment: 1) Honestly couldn't answer this. When it comes to low-level issues like this, I'm at a loss. All I did was install MINT on a hard-drive on a whim years ago(terrible, terrible idea. Really should've read up on it more.) and then decide on yet another whim to reinstall windows, then do it again when I installed Windows on the SSD and give myself a fresh start. 


2) I have the disk, and should feasibly be able to find a way into the recovery mode. As mentioned above however this is all over my head- why wouldn't you consider reinstalling the bootloader safe?

Comment: so the only valid install is the windows one on the ssd correct?  if so disconnect the others boot the ssd (recovery mode may  launch from a jacked up boot code (if so  follow prompts to repair bcd )  then reformat the other drives  and repurpose

Comment: Correct. SSD is the only drive with any OS on it. It seems as though GRUB is trying to look on whichever HDD I had previously installed Mint and Windows on, but they both fail to start. Windows gives me a bootmgr not found error and mint just dies after it finishes picking up my peripherals and leaves me in an empty console for eternity. I'll have to take a look at what's booting where, because when selecting the SSD and one of the HDDs in my BIOS, I get GRUB. The other HDD is the only thing that brings me back into Windows(Which for whatever reason thinks I have two copies but that's offtopic